# Ways to automate data in excel from various websites

Tags: automation, microsoft-excel, scraping

I work in IT for bank and my team work on obsolete software tech. So we have to daily make trackers to update our bank software with current ones in market. Every time We have to go on specific sites to check new versions and confirm if they are same and then update in our data tracker. Are there any methods to automate this?

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! Please note this site is about recommending *software,* not assets or [resources](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2470/185) like [howtos](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/882/185), [manuals/tutorials](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1258/185), best approaches etc. Considering this as an unfortunate phrasing let's assume you asked for software. Can you please read [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) and **[edit]** your question accordingly?

Comment: Especially missing: What OS should it run on (by Excel, I assume Windows), what prices are acceptible (including subscriptions?), must it be Excel or would a stand-alone software using a database also fit, could it be a (self-hosted / 3rd party provided) web service?